# What is order of complexity of below algorithm to find substring of given string

Tags: java, string, algorithm, big-o

I have written below code for finding whether a given char array is substring of main array.
Please tell what is the best case and worst case order of complexity for below code.

I feel this is very efficient algorithm with O(mainstring.lenth-substring.length) worst case complexity.

```
    public class SubstringOfString {


    public static boolean  isSubstring  (char[] main , char[] sub){

        int base=0 ;
        int i=0;

        while(i<sub.length){
            if(sub[i]!=main[base] && i >0 ){
            base=base-i;
                if (base>main.length-sub.length){
                    System.out.println("not found");
                    return false;   
                }

            }
            else {
                i++;base++;
            }

        }

        if (i==sub.length){
        System.out.println("found at"+(base-sub.length));
        return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        char[] main = "i am hello as hello well".toCharArray();
        char[] sub="hello".toCharArray();
        SubstringOfString.isSubstring(main,sub);

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think so, since you could give it two very long, identical strings. It would still check each character of those strings. Also, wouldn't this algorithm not work for main="aaab" and sub="aab"?

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615264/big-o-analysis-of-a-sub-string-of-string-algorithm-does-onlogn-simplify) for Big O analysis related to this topic. I don't actually believe you can get a Big O of n except with the use chase of a single char within a String.

Comment: @guest This works for main="aaab" and sub="aab"

Comment: did you mean to reset `i` too?

Answer (score 0):

Best case Complexity : O(substring.length)
Best Case : Substring found at starting of mainstring

Worst case Complexity: O(mainstring.length)
Worst Case:  Substring found at main.length-sub.length

Comment: think again your response.

Answer (score 0):

First, your current solution doesn't actually run with the example you provided: `base` quickly becomes negative.

Second the worst case run time is **(substring.length*mainstring.length)** since you have to backtrack a number of positions up to the substring length each time you find a non-matching char.

For example:

```
char[] main = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa".toCharArray(); //60 A's
char[] sub =  "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaB".toCharArray(); //15 A's
isSubstring(main,sub); //compares each 'a' in main up to 15 times
```